# How to Get the number of files included in a byte array?

Tags: c#

I am using `ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Core` library to zip the files in my C# code. After zipping i will return a byte array . Is there any way we can find the number of files in the byte array ?

my code looks like

```
string FilePath ="C:\HELLO";
 MemoryStream outputMemStream = new MemoryStream();
            ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputMemStream);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(string.Concat(FilePath, file));
                if (fi.Exists)
                {
                    var entryName = ZipEntry.CleanName(fi.Name);
                    ZipEntry newEntry = new ZipEntry(entryName);
                    newEntry.DateTime = DateTime.Now;
                    newEntry.Size = fi.Length;
                    zipStream.PutNextEntry(newEntry);

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                    var fs = File.OpenRead(string.Concat(FilePath, file));
                    var count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    while (count > 0)
                    {
                        zipStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);  
                    }
                }
            }
            zipStream.Close();
            byte[] byteArrayOut = outputMemStream.ToArray();
            return byteArrayOut;
```

Comment: Yes, you just load the bytes into a stream and create a `ZipInputStream`.

Answer (score 2):

A byte array is just what it is - a sequence of bytes. Knowing "the number of files" by just looking at a byte array can not be done. You'd need unzip the byte array.

However, as you loop over a set of files when zipping, it would be easy to increase a variable with every processed file and also return that.

*To account for the comments, it's probably easier to use an `out` parameter instead of a `Tuple`*

```
numFiles = 0;    // This is an out parameter to the method
foreach (var file in files)
{
    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(string.Concat(FilePath, file));
    if (fi.Exists)
    {
        numFiles++;
        ...
    }
}

...
return byteArrayOut;
```

Comment: Why use a `Tuple`? Just put an `out` parameter on the method.

Comment: Yes, you could do that, however, I'm personally not too fond of using `out` parameters. You are right, however, an `out` parameter is in many cases easier to handle.

Comment: The benefit with `out` is that you can now create a method overload that matches the original ignoring the extra parameter. `Tuple` might have involved substantial code changes and a method cannot by overloaded with only differing return types.

Comment: I totally agree with you, @leppie. Didn't consider this at first.

Answer (score 0):

You can return your object with 2 properties: zipped byte array and number of files.
Also, use string.Format (or Path.Combine) instead of string.Concat

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.80).aspx

use

```
var filesCount = 0;
```

out of the method

and

```
filesCount = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Length
```

before zip